# How to make private NPM packages in Github Packages available to workflow of another repository?

Tags: npm, github-actions

We are in a process of migration from on-premise solutions to github. There is project "pink" that needs some NPM packages to build but GH Actions cannot access them. All our npm packages are scoped to @organization and we have organization of the same name on github (I mean the URL http://github.com/organization)

I have moved the NPM package "violet" from on-premise Nexus to GH Packages with this steps:

1. Create "violet" repo on github
2. git clone "violet" on my local machine
3. Update package.json and .npmrc to remove references to local nexus:

   - remove "repository" from .npmrc completly
   - remove "publishConfig" from package.json
   - remove "repository" from package.json

Then I published NPM package to GH Packages:

1. `npm install --registry <on-premise-nexus> @organization/violet`
2. Change package.json of @organization/violet in local node_modules:

   - remove "publishConfig"
   - replace "repository" with github one (violet)
3. `npm login --registry https://npm.pkg.github.com` - I used my github username and github personal token (classic) as password. Login was successful.
4. `npm publish --registry https://npm.pkg.github.com node_modules/@organization/violet`

The package is published successfully. I can see it in Github Packages. Now I try to run Github Actions workflow of project "pink" which needs this package. It has dependency on @organization/violet. This is my github actions workflow:

```
- name: Use Node.js 16
  uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: 16.x
- run: echo "@organization:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" >> ~/.npmrc
- run: npm ci
```

"npm ci" step always fails with `403 Forbidden - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=***/@organization%2fviolet - Permission denied`

I also tried my personal token as _authToken - no luck too

Locally I can run `npm install --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/ @organization/violet` only after I first login like in point 3. It doesn't work when I'm not logged in and add my github token as `:_authToken` to the URL.

I have added access to package to "pink" repository in Package settings but it doesn't help either.

How can I access this package from Github Actions workflow?

Comment: You may need to add the packages permission to your workflow. 

`permissions: packages: read`
https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages

Comment: @aknosis Nope, I tried that :(

Comment: It may be a setting on the package itself. Navigate to package settings page https://github.com/orgs/{org}/packages/npm/{package}/settings and then under "Manage Actions access" add the repo where the workflows exist. @amorfis

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. It turned out URL with appended `_authToken` does not work, at least for scoped repositories. It works when repository is defined separately from `_authToken`. I do it by `npm config` but probably echo to `.npmrc` would work too

```
- run: echo "@organization:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com >> ~/.npmrc
- run: npm config set //npm.pkg.github.com:_authToken="${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```